# messed up keys after permanently remapping

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, xkb

My <kbd>Alt</kbd> key doesn't work anymore, so I thought to remap it with <kbd>R Shift</kbd> and while doing it I messed up the shift keys for both the <kbd>L Shift</kbd> and <kbd>R Shift</kbd>.

As my password contains an `@` character. I can't use `sudo` even without doing on-screen keyboard, as it works like an <kbd>Alt</kbd> functionality now.

The remapping functionality of <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is gone.
How to reset it back without using `sudo` option?

I am using `xkb` as I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the changes I made were saved in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short,

1. boot into recovery mode,
2. remount the root file system in write-enabled mode with

   ```sh
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
3. and reinstall the packages that contain the original keyboard layouts:

   ```sh
   dpkg-query -S /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc |
   sed -e 's/:.*//;s/, /\n/g' | sort -u |
   xargs apt-get install -f --reinstall
   ```

   On most installations that will be equivalent to:

   ```sh
   apt-get install -f --reinstall xkb-data
   ```

Comment: My `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` was messed up as well, and I had not taken a backup. This helped recover my system. Thanks!